# Launching java app with uri passing parameters

Tags: java, parameters, uri

I have a java app, and i want to open it with an URI. I've got it, making an exe from the jar, and registering it,  and it works. The problem is how can i pass to it parameters. 
For instance, if I link " E2L://moodle" i want my app to open moodle  url, if I link " E2L://google" I want the app to open the google url.

Can anybody help me please? Thank you

Comment: Clarify: Did you use a utility to convert a JAR file to a Windows  EXE file and you want to know how to pass parameters to the Windows EXE and have your main() accept the parameters when Windows auto-launches your EXE from an explorer folder double-click?

Comment: I want my main() accept the parameters when I make click on a link in a local html page. The link is like " E2L://xxxxx" ,  and I want my app to receive the xxxxxx parameter

Comment: Midua, Thanks for the clarification.  Maybe add the HTML tag to get more visibility and snag the right expert.

Comment: I think, the expert I need is a Java expert, because the problem is how to get the parameters in the java app....

Comment: were you able to find any answers?