# launch java app with uri passing parameters on mac

Tags: java, osx-yosemite, deep-linking

this question is similar to [Launching java app with uri passing parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669861/launching-java-app-with-uri-passing-parameters)
but perhaps i might ask it a different way

My goal is for users to install my application and them visit my website.. When they click on a link with an id, to open my installed app with the id passed in as an argument.

I would like to get it working on windows and mac (different aproaches) but wanted to start with mac.

### **Things i have Tried**

I used http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html
to create a app bundle then i edited Info.list to include

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
    <string>Webpage Helper</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>webpagehelper</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</array>
```

so my installed app will be used as the external protocol handler (like maget: for bit torrents)
the user then clicks on

```
<a href="webpagehelper:Launcher/id=USERID"}>Start</a>
```

And chrome asks the user if its ok to launch my app (which is fine) and launches it. Which is great BUT
I can not figure out how pass in "Launcher/id=USERID" as an argument to the java app

---

I have used other App Bundlers like
https://github.com/yangjian/appbundler
which does support passing arguments but I dont know if/how they work with uri triggered launch?

will i need to write something my self?
any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't the parameter be passed as a command line argument?

Comment: no it doesnt seem to be. if i use the appbundler from http://docs.oracle.com it doesnt al all. of i use appbundler from https://github.com/yangjian/appbundler then it does accept argument but still not if it launched by a uri on a browser

Comment: did you get any solutions?